# Updating pointer address in function, when passed as an argument. [ passing pointer as reference in C]

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, pass-by-reference, dereference

CONCEPT: Passing pointer by reference

Trying to achieve: To get updated pointer address from function, when passed as an argument.

```
int main(void)
{
    uint8_t unArray[10] = {0};  // unint8_t is type def as unsigned char
    uint8_t * pmyPtr;

    pmyPtr = unArray;

    func(pmyPtr);

    *pmyPtr = someValue3; 

}

void func(uint8_t * unPtr)
{
    *unPtr = someValue1;
     unPtr++;
    *unPtr = someValue2;  
     unPtr++;  

}
```

Suppose we have unArray address as 0x0001000. So pmyPtr will have 0x0001000 as its assigned a constant pointer.

When pointer is passed to the function func some indexes of array (first two) are updated by DE-referencing.

When I come back to the main after func execution I am trying to update the third index. How can this be achieved. I have a hunch that double De-referencing might be handy.

Comment: Return incremented pointer from function `func` and save value into that. Later access this array using old saved pointer and of course you need to change the prototype according to that.

Comment: @Dayalrai Yes, This is a possible solution, but I want to avoid this approach. I want o grab the concept of updating pointer by reference when passed as an argument.

Comment: Shouldn't `uint8_t * pmyPtr;` read `uint8_t * myPtr;`?

Comment: @vishram0709 *myPtr will not update the third index, rather it will update the first. Try debugging in your IDE. Thankyou

Comment: @alk Thank you. that was a typo. Updated

Comment: OT: It's at least `int main(void)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct. A pointer to pointer is a simple solution. In c++ it could be syntactically hidden as a reference.

```
main()
{
    uint8_t unArray[10] = {0};  // unint8_t is type def as unsigned char
    uint8_t * myPtr;

    myPtr = unArray;

    func(&myPtr);//NOTICE ADDRESS TAKING

    *myPtr = someValue3; 

}

void func(uint8_t ** unPtrPtr)//ONE MORE STAR
{
    uint8_t * unPtr=*unPtrPtr;//CHANGED
    *unPtr = someValue1;
     unPtr++;
    *unPtr = someValue2;  
     unPtr++;
    *unPtrPtr = unPtr;//CHANGED
}
```

Comment: This method of using a local pointer is good, since it gives far better readability than working directly with the pointer to pointer. Nobody wants to read code that looks like `*(*unPtrPtr)++;`

Comment: @Osaid OK, I now added all the #defines, compiled (on Linux), and it works: **BEFORE myPtr=0xbfa89332
AFTER  myPtr=0xbfa89334
**. Should I edit my answer to include the debug printf's?

Comment: _gcc_ on Linux is known to put constants in a read-only segment, so that trying to update constant strings can cause core dumps, but in this example `myPtr` is perfectly modifiable by any standard. @Osaid what is your environment?

Comment: @MadaaKaama You are right, was skipping the last line [*unPtrPtr = unPtr;] This is the core.

Comment: @MaadaKaama The IDE is HEW (coding in C) running on Windows